Extract non tagged areas in OSM
OpenStreetMap contains depending on the region, a lot of light orange, not yet tagged areas:

-> in Openstreetmap
Is there a way to extract just these areas (attribute like "not tagged" or something like this)?
The workaround would probably clip these areas with the tagged areas.

I'd probably try to save it as raster and use some kind of formula, but I'm not anywhere near sure this is the best option.
